# Catalog URL Rewrites Duplicate Index (HY002)

Tags: catalog, url, indexing, overrides, mysql-indexes

I've seen this problem all around the internet and have yet to find a reasonable solution yet. I've truncated the core_url_rewrite table, set my permissions properly, etc.

It seems there is an issue when actually performing the query, duplicate data is being inserted into the table, and no exception is thrown, causing the script to hang indefinitely. All other indexes work fine. The table has about 300,000+ records. So any number of these could be causing an issue.

I've pruned the database to make sure products do not share the same SKU, as that was also one of the recommended solutions. I'm not exactly sure what the indexer is doing specifically that would cause this conflict. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have customer attributes that a multiselect? I had this issue and when I changed them to dropdown I was able to re-index. What version are you using? This should be fixed in the most recent.

Comment: I am using the latest CE. Can you please clarify your answer? Where is this option in the admin panel?

Comment: Magento has/had a fix for this that we have applied to other 1.7 site. I am attaching the PATCH. The particular problem we had was new URLs being generated each time the index was performed. I don't know how to attach a file.

Comment: I would recommend [gist](http://gist.github.com) or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com). Copy paste the contents of the patch file there and share the link here, or as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have similar problem with duplicating records. The problem appear because of this checkbox
https://www.monosnap.com/image/nWkoCm1itaDaZE86PEK9ypVAO
*Create Permanent Redirect for old URL* 
and product names are equal.

There is a fix we've used on one of the projects 
https://gist.github.com/vdubyna/6162493